# Not sure how to label an OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have an html document that has a form where selecting the button activates a program that runs a robotic arm, however, I also need to have this button link to another page. Based on the research I have done previously, I think an OnClick event would do exactly what I need it to. My problem is that I am not quite sure how to reference both the robot command and the link to another page.

```
<td style="width: 120px; height: 47px"><form action="../../Karel/RIGHT1" method="GET">
                    <div align="left">
                      <input type="hidden" name="object" value="numreg">
                      <input type="hidden" name="operate" value="setint">
                      <input type="hidden" name="index" value="1">
                      <input type="hidden" name="value" value="0">                                                   
                      <input type="image" src="onegrey.jpg" name="submit" border="0"  width="137">
                      <a href="rightmanual.stm" onclick=""
                      <a href="left.stm" target="_blank"><img src="leftnotavailable.jpg" border="0" alt="rightmanual.stm"/></div>
                  </form>
```

The ..//../Karel/RIGHT1 is the robot program the document is trying to call and rightmanual.stm is the page I need to also link to when the image/button onegrey.jpg is selected. I tried to be as specific as possible,thanks for any help that is sent my way.

Comment: Is this question really related to Java? You probably mean JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to redirect to another page on form submit? If this is the case, add an id tag to the input, with a name eg. "btnRedirect".

```
<input id="btnRedirect" type="image" src="onegrey.jpg" name="submit" border="0"  width="137">
```

You can then use jQuery for an onclick event. More on [jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/) here.

```
<head>
<script>
$.('#btnRedirect').click(function() {
window.location.href = "http://www.url.com";
})
</script>
<head>
```

Or you can just add an onClick event to your submit button

```
<input type="image" src="onegrey.jpg" name="submit" onClick="location.href='index.html'" border="0"  width="137">
```